# Custom Wordpress Theme showing jumbled mess in navigation

Tags: sql, wordpress

I installed a new Wordpress template I coded onto a company's server. However, when I went to preview it before activating, it looked totally wrong (the navigation had all these different words in there from another page opposed to the navigation links I programmed in). I deleted the old SQL database and added my own- what could be causing this? Thanks for any advice.

The site SHOULD look like: www.kleanir.com

But instead looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/bLBFWCO.png)

Comment: My guess is that there is a CSS issue with the new menu. Instead of previewing the new theme make a copy of the site and activate it to make sure the issue isn't with the preview view.

Comment: That was part of the problem, @Fencer04! I had to redo the menu and change a few things, and that did the trick! Thanks for your help!